# Inserting data into multiple columns of same table from one column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, vertica

I have a table `WCR (l,j,W,C,R)` with the following entries. Here, `l,j` are primary keys.

[image]

I have to insert data from column `C` of `WCR` into another table `C(l,C1,C2)` where `l` is the primary key. The `C` table will be as follows -

[image]

For each `l`, `j=1` will be inserted in `C1`, and `j=2` will be inserted into `C2`.
But I can not generalize the queries.

I have tried statements like -

```
INSERT INTO C 
SELECT 1, 
C FROM WCR WHERE j=1, 
C FROM WCR WHERE j=2;
```

and subqueries in Insert statement like -

```
 INSERT INTO C 
 VALUES (1, 
         SELECT C FROM WCR WHERE j=1, 
         SELECT C FROM WCR WHERE j=2);
```

But none of them works in Vertica as it doesn't support subquery in `INSERT` statement and the first one is invalid. How can I efficiently Insert the values into `C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses a `join`:

```
Insert into C(l, c1, c2)
    select wcr1.l, wcr1.c, wcr2.c
    from wcr wcr1 join
         wcr wcr2
         on wcr1.l = wcr2.l and wcr1.j = 1 and wcr2.j = 2;
```

Another method uses conditional aggregation:

```
insert into c(l, c1, c2)
     select l, max(case when j = 1 then c end) as c1, max(case when j = 2 then c end)
     from wcr
     group by l;
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first statement. I know its a typo, in the second line, it should be "select wcr1.l" instead of "select wcr1.j".

The second one works perfectly.